Meaning of "Av Harachamim"
Time-sensitive question (today is 29 Elul..!)
Artscroll translates the phrase "Av Harachamim" as "father of mercy".
What does this mean exactly? How can G-d be the Father of a Midah (character trait)?
Is it analogous to the phrase, "he was the father of modern medicine" (father meaning "founder" or "progenitor")? What would that mean exactly anyway?
Or does it perhaps mean something like "paragon"?
Sources for any answers requested, the older the better.

an Av melacha isn't actually anyone's father

It's just another way of saying "merciful father"

This is perhaps meant in the sense that HaShem is our Father (e.g., Y'sha'yahu 64:7) to whom mercies belong (Daniyeil 9:9) and who bestows those mercies upon us as a father does to his children (T'hillim 103:13). A "soccer mom", by comparison (lehavdil), is not the mother of a soccer ball, but rather a mother who is involved in her children's soccer activities.

@RabbiKaii I'm sure there's plenty of depth to it, but grammatically speaking, "father of mercy" can be read like "a man of great wisdom." It's not obvious that Artscroll was saying anything more.

Here's a nice nugget of depth from Likkutei Torah: https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=47723#p577286

@shmosel there is already a phrase that means "merciful father". It's "Av Harachaman", which is the nusach sfard version in the phrase, "mi camocha av harachaman".
"Av harachamim" must mean something different, because nusach sfard change between the 2 during the aseret yemei teshuva

Yes, my link addresses that. I'm just saying the literal meaning is more like "paragon" than "progenitor."

I have a similar question regarding המלך המשפט. In both cases the second word acts as an adjective while being a noun.

@shmosel, Moshe Rabbeinu is "av haneviim" which one would take as "paragon of prophets". So I agree with you about peshat of the words in the siddur and machzor. But, many darshen out how Moshe was also the progenitor, eg his prophecy was the conduit by which the other neviim.got theirs. So I am sure similar derashos exist here too.

Also, notice the implied difference between two idioms in the siddur: אב הרחמים in contrast to אב הרחמן. The latter is much easier to understand – "Compassionate Father".

Totally not related, but maybe a nice additon.... The Imrei Pinchas (Rabbi Koritzer) explains that the gematria of dvas (honey) is av harachamim and that is why we dip in honey on Rosh Hashanah.

It is similar to our blessing of גומל חסדים טובים (bestows beneficient kindnesses) in a multifold form, so is אב הרחמים - a father of multifold mercies. Perhaps, it is connected to the fact that grammatically speaking, both main names of Hashem - E-lohim and A-donai - are plural of the forms (E-loah and A-doni).
The language of father comes from the midrash Bereshis Rabbati Vayishlach 12 on Bereshis 33:3 "and he (Yaakov) himself went on ahead of (his wives and children to greet Eisav)

(my translation may need correction) The verse Tehilim 103:13: Like a father has mercy for his children, (so the LORD has mercy for those who fear Him). Our rabbis said that so taught Yoav to David, as he said that he wondered if really a father is more merciful to his children than their mother. Is not she greatly merciful to them as she troubles herself with pregnancy, birth, and raising them? And he (David) said yes, but did not give a fitting answer. So Yoav went to find out to see whether the saying is true and what it means. He encircled entire land of Israel and found one elderly man among many and who had 12 sons and who could provide for their needs with difficulty with earnings of his entire day. Yoav asked him if he would sell him one of the sons and this way he would provide for his wife and other children. The man scolded him. So Yoav went to his wife and spoke to her at lenghth and at the end he bought a son from her for a 100 gold dinars. In the late evening the elderly man came home to eat and did not find one son. He asked where he was. His wife spoke so and so and in a roundabout way showed him 100 dinars. The man understood what happened, he became very angry and did not sleep entire night. In the morning he rose, took those dinars, he took his weapons in his hands and went to find the big man (gavra) who bought his son. The elderly man did not ask details (of the sale) and did not weigh the money until he found Yoav. So he said to him, "I will not be adding to complete the payment, but if you will not retun my son either I will kill you or you will kill me". Yoav heard the man, he took the money and returned his son. So Yoav said: indeed David said correctly: "Like a father has mercy on his children and not like a mother has mercy on her children. Such is a fact, the mother would sell me her son so that she would not be working as hard to provide for her children, but the father exerted himself in providing for the family and was ready to sacrifice himself to kill for his son. That is what it means "like a father has mercy on his children".

